# is $f(x)$ in big-$O$ of $g(x)$ assuming the following?

Tags: asymptotics

Assuming that: $f(n)=O(g(n))$ and $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are nondecreasing and always bigger than 1

Is the following necessarily true?

> $$f(n)\log_2(f(n)^c)=O(g(n)\log_2(g(n)))$$

And also, could you explain why? Thanks.

Comment: What is $c$? Did you want $\log_2(g(n)^c)$ too?

Comment: Sorry, $c$ is a constant, I don't get the latter part of your question.

Comment: Yeah, ignore the second part, the $c$ really doesn't matter - if it is true when $c=1$ then it is true for arbitrary $c>0$.

Comment: When trying out $f(x)=g(x)=2^x$
I get $cx=O(2^xx)$
Does this make sense?

Comment: Please stick with either $n$ or the variable $x$. Switching between them is confusing. In particular, when using $n$, we conventionally assume $n\to\infty$, while $x$ could be $x\to 1$ or $x\to 0$ or $x\to +\infty$ or whatever.

Comment: With $f(n)=g(n)=2^n$, then you want $cn2^n=O(n2^n)$, which is pretty obviously true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can prove that $\log f(n) = O(\log g(n))$ you are done.

Letting $C_0$ be such that $f(n)< C_0 \cdot g(n)$ for all $n$.

Then $\log f(n) < \log C_0+ \log g(n)$

Let $D=\log g(1)$. Then $$\log C_0 = \frac{C_0}{D} \log g(1) \leq \frac{C_0}{D} \log g(n)$$

This means that $\log f(n) < \left(\frac{\log C_0}{D} +1\right)\log g(n)$

(We need $g(n)$ non-decreasing for that last inequality. We really don't need that strong a condition. I believe all you need is $\liminf_{n\to\infty}g(n)>1$.)

So $$f(n)\log f(n)< C_0 g(n) \left(\frac{\log C_0}{D}+1\right)\log g(n)= Fg(n)\log g(n)$$

where $F=C_0\left(\frac{\log C_0}{D}+1\right)$.

Note, we can always pick $C_0>1$, so we don't need to worry about the sign of $\log C_0$.

Finally, the constant $c$ is irrelevant, since $f(n)\log f(n)^c=cf(n)\log f(n)<cF\cdot g(n)\log n$.

Note that you need $\liminf g(n) >1$. For example, if $g(n)=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(n)=2$, then $f(n)=O(g(n))$, but $f(n)\log_2 f(n)=2$ and $g(n)\log_2 g(n)=O(\frac{1}{n})$